# What does a green number on an item mean?

Tags: endless-battle

I have 3 trinkets and was going to replace one of the equipped ones with a new one.  However, this trinket has a green number in its stats:

[image: Green Value]

However, from the information I can see, this appears to be the lesser trinket.  This is the other one I have equipped:

[image: Better one?]

The game has right-click to equip functionality, and when trying to equip my new one, the level 12 trinket is the one removed.  I am unsure if the game will automatically get rid of the lower quality, but if it does that means the level 8 item is better than the level 12.

Is there anything special to an item with a green value for a stat?

Comment: I believe the green number means that the "Fortified" affix means that it has a boosted armor level.

Comment: I'm not sure it's tied to the "Fortified" keyword.  I have some non-fortified items [also with green stats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5OHyO.png), though most of the blue items I have have green stats.  Then again, none of my green items have green stats.

Comment: Right, but the blue items can have increased stats because of their rarity. Usually with green items, the name of the item is preceded or followed by a word(s) that correspond to what stat they are increasing. Fortified will, in my experience, always increase the base armor of an item. Green base stats just mean that they are higher than normal items' stats would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reddit post by the game's dev in it he posts a [comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/24d20y/endless_battle_rpg_incremental/ch61m5w) about item colors.

UPDATE: someone [asked this very question](http://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/24d20y/endless_battle_rpg_incremental/ch6hbfo) deeper in the post.

Comment: Those comments are related to the color of the item.  In my screenshots you can see White gloves and Green boots, for example.  The stats I am comparing are both for White "Common" items.  I was wondering why the first has a green number for Armor stat while the second has a white number.

Comment: edited my post with more info